# Is there a CSS way to decrease the distance between a text and a horizontal rule?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have the following text in a rmarkdown file and would like to decrease the distance between the horizontal rule and the text. Is there a way to do it in CSS? I saw one LATEX solution, but I would like to know it in CSS.

```
noaçlijchaçlkjcn

***
```

[image: print with the distance signalized]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the Bootstrap CSS, by decreasing the value of `margin-top`property (default value is `20px`). To get that value you can *[Inspect](https://rstudio4edu.github.io/rstudio4edu-book/css-crash.html)* the source:

[image]

If you need to change "the distance between the horizontal rule and the text" in one or more places (not all), you may use `<hr style=" " />` instead of [three or more asterisks](https://markdown-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#horizontal-rules) `***`, dashes `---`, or underscores `___`:

```
noaçlijchaçlkjcn

<hr style="margin-top: -10px" />
```

or, if you need to change the default horizontal rule (`hr`) values for the whole document, use:

````
```{css hr-content, echo = FALSE}
hr {
    margin-top: -10px;
    # margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```
````

This `css` chunk is to be placed under the `YAML`.